# Can I delete avast in programdata?

Tags: avast, home-folder

I have a avast software folder in my programdata and I'm pretty sure it's junk, I already uninstalled avast through control panel/deleting so should I delete the avast folder in programdata? I do have admin permissions but my issue is if it is safe and should I do it, my programdata folder has a lot of gigabytes so I should probably delete unneeded junk.

Comment: a) I doubt that it is very large, b) I would get that junk off of my hard disk ASAP.. yes.. you should be able to delete it if you have uninstalled Avast.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas But are you sure it won't do anything harmful?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas If so, does that mean I can delete any appdata that is from apps I deleted?

Comment: See @John answer below.  He is no dummy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgramData is not at all like Program Files (which are secured).

You can delete things from ProgramData so long as a program is not locking the file, and you are sure it is junk, then just delete it.

No harm but just be sure you or Avast does not need the file

Comment: So if I uninstalled Avast I can be sure that it's junk?

Comment: Yes. Quite sure about that